# Zebra EMDK error GENERAL_EXCEPTION_OCCURED when loading profiles in Xamarin after updating to Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, xamarin, motorola-emdk, zebra

I have an application that I have built for Zebra CC6000 that has been working fine for the past 3 years and no issues updating the code and rebuilding, but recently when I updated to Visual Studio 2022 for Visual Studio 2019 and built the application it is no longer able to load the profiles setup in the EMDK Manager.

The profiles are there, just I get the extended status: **GENERAL_EXCEPTION_OCCURED**
The above error is from EMDKResults.EXTENDED_STATUS_CODE
Digging further, I see that this error is generated: **Failed to connect dependency services.**

```
// Assign the 'ProfileName' used in EMDKConfig.xml
string profileName = "UnitClock";

// Assign the 'emdk_name' used in EMDKConfig.xml for the 'PowerMgr' feature that used for name-value pairs
string featureName = "Clock1";
string[] modifyData = new string[2];
modifyData[0] = ProfileManager.CreateNameValuePair(featureName, "Date", newDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
modifyData[1] = ProfileManager.CreateNameValuePair(featureName, "Time", newDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

// Call processPrfoileAsync with profile name, 'Set' flag and modify data to update the profile
EMDKResults results = profileManager.ProcessProfile(profileName, ProfileManager.PROFILE_FLAG.Set, modifyData);
string resTx = results.ExtendedStatusCode.ToString();
```

I am using Zebra CC6000 devices running Android 8.1 And Android 10.

Going back to VS2019 did not solve the issue.
Also, I tried EMDK version 8 and EMDK version 6, but same results.

I tried adding the below to the manifest which is for A11 and greater, but no change also.

```xml
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.symbol.emdk.emdkservice" />
</queries>
```

The dependancey is setup as:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(myApp.Droid.BarcodeScannerService))]
```

I have spent the past week pouring through the code and online for answers, but am at my wits end.